# Syntax for SQL function, in variables and return

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I have a sql function called task2.sql:

```
-- script to create function task2
CREATE OR REPLACE Function task2
 (input_userid IN integer)
begin
return (select * 
     from tweet twt
     where twt.userid = input_userid
     order by publishtime desc, tweetid desc);


END;
/
exit;
```

I'm trying to return all the rows with the goal being to write them to a text file. I'm using a java file to call this function and to manage the results. I am messing up the syntax somewhere. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is usually product specific functionality. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Oracle functions from what I remember only return one value. You can either define a custom table type and return that or create a stored procedure. You can also make use of out parameters but that is not recommended.

Comment: You should always specify the columns to return explicitly instead of using `SELECT *` to prevent your resultset including additional columns (and breaking your file structure) if they get added in the future, and to give you a solid error message if a column you are using gets dropped.

Comment: Is there any way to just dump all the info into a string and then return that?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle functions can't do this in such way. For returning rows from function you should use `Table Function` (with pipeline may be)
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm#CHDCIEJG

**But**, for  wrapping query into **procedure** i can reccomend you return `SYS_REFCURSOR`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE task2
 (input_userid IN integer, out_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
begin
 OPEN out_cur FOR select * 
     from tweet twt
     where twt.userid = input_userid
     order by publishtime desc, tweetid desc;
END;
```

Then, you should fetch rows from `out_cur` in your application. It's easy and google and SF full of this examples. For example [read data from SYS_REFCURSOR in a Oracle stored procedure and reuse it in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290951/read-data-from-sys-refcursor-in-a-oracle-stored-procedure-and-reuse-it-in-java)

Comment: You can have a function that returns a sys_refcursor too. Either way you get a result set that the Java side can process though.